# Python class instances stored in a list to store seperate instances

Tags: python, class, variables, global

```
from datetime import datetime

class sms_store:
    def __init__(self):
        self.store = [] #Keeps resetting / not saving data from previous instances
        self.message_count = 0 #Keeps resetting / not saving data from previous instances
    def add_new_arrival(self,number,time,text):
        self.store.append(("From: "+number, "Recieved: "+time,"Msg: "+text))
        self.message_count += 1

newsms = sms_store()
time = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
newsms.add_new_arrival("23456",time, "hello, how are you?")
```

As seen above in the comment section i want to a list to store information from VARIOUS instances. Not one instance, but SEVERAL seperate instances of information and the list being a list that is accessible and in which I can edit it and it SAVES the information from different instances. Its not doing this. It is resetting after every instance.

I have tried the global variable route but not understanding it and dont think it will work. I have set a global variable OUTSIDE the class and created an object inside the class to store in the list but it gives me an error: **UnboundLocalError: local variable 'message_count' referenced before assignment**.

I am working on an excercise that requires one to use classes in the interactive python site: http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/classes_and_objects_I.html#term-class

Please please help me.

Comment: You should only create *one* `store` variable, then reuse that. That is what I told you in my answer on your other question. You are creating a *new* store for every SMS. Don't do that!

Comment: as a global variable, it should be declared `global message_count`.

Comment: @Elazar: no, we just steered the OP away from that. That is not a good practice to teach.

Comment: I agree. I just explained the UnboundLocalError thing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters hey again, i still dont quite understand what you mean by "one store variabe" please can you explain or give an example of how i would do it?

Comment: @user2318861: Create one sms_store instance, once: store = sms_store(). Then never create another sms_store instance in your code. Just use store.add_new_arrival() for each new SMS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python global variable and class functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210314/python-global-variable-and-class-functionality)

Comment: Your question has already been answered in the previous question you asked; both Eric and I tell you to only create one store and reuse that store.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks again. You were right. I created the class STATIC variables (I think thats the term?) as a docstring (Above all class methods/functions). Then I created ONE instance. Then used the object of the instant to keep appending and it records and saves data. thanks again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want a class variable.

The code should look like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

class Sms_store:
    store = []
    message_count = 0

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def add_new_arrival(self,number,time,text):
        Sms_store.store.append(("From: "+number, "Recieved: "+time,"Msg: "+text))
        Sms_store.message_count += 1

newsms1 = Sms_store()
time = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
newsms1.add_new_arrival("23456",time, "hello, how are you?")

newsms2 = Sms_store()
time = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
newsms2.add_new_arrival("23456",time, "hello, how are you?")

print Sms_store.store
```

This way, the variables `store` and `message_count` will be shared by all the instances of the `Sms_store` class.

Comment: Then your class has no *point*. There is no instance state here, why use a class at all then? And I already covered this in the other question the OP asked.

Comment: Either use functions (make the module the API and singleton), or use a global holding one class instance. Having a class with only class variables only serves to confuse.

Comment: He asked how to do it.. I told him

Comment: Also, unless you have some performance reason, `message_count` is synonymous with `len(Sms_store.store)`, so is needlessly duplicative.

Comment: @sr2222 you might not want to call `len()` every time for performance purposes. depends on how big the list is.

Comment: Thanks alot. Yes, I created the two variables above all the class' functions. It now saves. Just an addition to add that you should just create ONE instance and then use an object to keep appending such as this: **store = sms_store() \n
store.add_new_arrival("12345",time,"Hello how are you?")**

Comment: @IonutHulub If you have performance concerns, adding another series of operations (attribute access+add+assign) to every call to `add_new_arrival` with the `+=` could be worse than a `len()` call, if you don't frequently look up the length.  You could also memoize the `len` value in some way.  It's all premature optimization of code that is inefficient in many more significant ways anyway though.

Comment: @IonutHulub No matter how big the list is. [`len(list)` is `O(1)`](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Comment: @IonutHulub it wont let me use the len. When I type message_count = len(Sms_store.sort) it returns with **NameError: name 'sms_store' is not defined**

Comment: @user2318861. you can use `len(Sms_store.store)`

Answer (score 1):

You should not create a new instance of sms_store each time:

```
newsms = sms_store()
newsms.add_new_arrival("23456", datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'), "hello, how are you?")
newsms.add_new_arrival("65432", datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'), "I'm fine, thanks")
```

works just fine